# is it possible to use href and javascript:void both in <a> tag?

Tags: jquery, html

is it possible to have

```
<a href="index.php" > click </a>
```

that doesn't change page location on click on link? i know that 'javascript:void(0);' should be used if we don't want the location change on click,but i need to determine the link href to be used in some jquery codes.

Comment: are you sure the code you posted visualizes correctly, because with what you put there there's nothing wrong and it's kind of different from the question title

Comment: @Ican I feel like he just wants to use href as an id or data field

Comment: @Ican,i know the code i written is right.it is standard form of <a> tag but i want something else.i got my answer below.anyway... thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the onclick javascript event of your link to `return false`. It will do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can `return false` from a click handler to prevent navigation.

Answer (score 1):

you can do following:

```
myElement.onclick = function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  //now you can use href attribute
}
```

Comment: don't forget to check `window.event` and set `returnValue` to `false` for Internet Explorer